# What to use: 'of' or 'out of'?

Tags: numbers, numerals

Good evening. My question refers to proportions. I would like to ask you whether it is better to say '10 of 100 people' or '10 out of 100 people'? Is the second phrase ('out of') more formal than the first one ('of')?

Comment: Both are correct..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've heard *10 of 100 people* used, particularly where it relates specifically to a survey of 100 people (effectively saying 10 people from a survey of 100), but it's unusual.

*10 out of 100 people* is the more commonly used option of the two.

Other options would include:

- 10 out of every 100 people
- 10 in 100 people
- 1 in 10 people
- 10 percent of people