# 'Make the best of' or 'Make the best out of.'

Tags: phrase-usage

I was all by myself, no one there to support me mentally or financially. I though in order to survive I had to start buying cheap things, spend less and sell the unnecessary things. And I said to myself:
"I have to **make the best of** whatever I have."

I don't know if the sentence is correct given the context. But if it is, how about "I have to **make the best out of** whatever I have"?

Comment: _Make the best of_ is fine. There are online definitions of it which you could have looked up.

Comment: The additional preposition ***out*** is syntactically valid, but idiomatically it's not common in your exact context.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What to use: 'of' or 'out of'?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/94335/what-to-use-of-or-out-of) See also [Using “of” or “out of” big confusion](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/253313/using-of-or-out-of-big-confusion)

Comment: Do all these sentences sound good? 1. Make the best of your time. 2. Make the best of everything you have. 3.Make the best of this opportunity.